# SQL: how to get rows containing only certain ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-division

I've got the following table:

```
+--------+--------+
|  group |  user  |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      2 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to select group, containing both user 1 and 2 and *only* 1 and 2 (not 3 or 42).

I tried

```
SELECT `group` FROM `myTable` 
WHERE `user` = 1 OR `user` = 2 
GROUP BY `group`;
```

But that of course gives me groups 1 and 2 while group 2 contains also user 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT `group` 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user` ORDER BY `user`) = '1,2';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faee4/3)

Comment: You beat me by seconds! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
SELECT `group` 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user` ORDER BY `user`) = '1,2';
```